# Perturbation theory in math and quantum mechanics

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

This question is about my lets say lack of understanding. I can not make the connection between what i study and what i saw in lectures.

For example in our QM lectures we saw perturbation theory like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics))
$$ H_0 |n_0\rangle=E_0^{(n)}|n_0\rangle $$
where $E_0^{(n)}$ are eigenvalues and $|n_0\rangle$ are eigenvectors of operator $H_0$.(Of course there are some other conditions like non-degeneracy etc but it doesn't matter for my question.) then we perturb it like this
$$ (H_0+ \lambda V) |n\rangle=E_n|n\rangle$$
This is just standart perturbation theory in any physics book or (first) quantum mechanics lecture.

But i study quantum mechanics and related mathematical topics in more rigorous manner as much as i can. Actually from these two books "Teschl G. - Mathematical methods in quantum mechanics" and "Konrad Schmüdgen (auth.) - Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space".

In these books they talk about Kato-Rellich theorem, Weyl theorem, KLMN theorem, Aronszajn–Donoghue Theory of Rank One Perturbations etc. but i cannot connect my knowledge from these "perturbation theory" to other "perturbation theory". I just cannot connect them i tried to look at some other books (Of course i just skim over them) but cannot find the connection. If someone is able to share or point me to this wonderful knowledge i would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: One thing to note is that there are many perturbation approaches for different matters. They are all called perturbation theory, but they are applied in other ways and on other entities. Like computation methods, there are turing machines, restricted turing machines (eg DFAs), quantum machines. They are called computation models but they differ

Comment: Yes thank you , for example kato-rellich theorem is not a "computational" thing it just talks about under what conditions peturbed self-adjoint operator stays self-adjoint.  Remaning self-adjoint is important because well observables need to be self-adjoint. But i wanted to see some computation that connects my 2 different QM knowledge.

Comment: For this I think more context is required in your question. Add some concrete examples which baffle you

Comment: Take a look at these notes: http://people.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/212a/10.pdf

Comment: The QM lectures (implicitly?) assume that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be expanded in (convergent) series. The rigorous  math books are concerned with proving this. See also [Kato, Perturbation theory for linear operators](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for reference, i checked this book because it is apparently a classic in this topic but as i said i just skimmed over it to find what i want but i couldn't. If you can share any specific part or page that would be nice

Comment: On p. 370 there is the magickal theorem that (under conditions) eigenvalues in infinite dimensional spaces behave like in finite dimensions. (BTW, you need to put @username (with no spaces and followed by a space) for a person to be notified of your comment.)

Comment: Also we have this book  "P. D. Hislop, I. M. Sigal (auth.) - Introduction to Spectral Theory_ With Applications to Schrödinger Operators". At Chapter 15 we have perturbation of discrete spectrum which is what was i looking for.